# TypeError int object is not iterable (beginner)

Tags: python, syntax, int, typeerror

I have some typeError problems with my python code. I get int object is not iterable and I have no idea why. I'm very much of a beginner.

```
# coding=utf8
def main():
numbers = input ("Enter numbers: ")
numbers = int(numbers)
list(numbers)

print ("\nNumbers (lowest): %s " % min(numbers))
print ("Numbers (all numbers) %s " % numbers)
print ("Numbers (highest): %s " % max(numbers))

print ("Numbers (mean value) %s " % sum // len(numbers))   
print ("Numbers (summary) %s " % sum(numbers))


main()
```

Comment: What do you expect `int(numbers)` to do? What do you type in after `Enter numbers: `?

Comment: What do you expect `list(numbers)` to do, given that `numbers` is currently an `int`?

Comment: let me chime in and suggest you put in one line of comment for like each line of code, or write the procedure in pseudo-code like you would expect a recipe to be written; that would help a lot. My guess is that there's  a hazy feeling but no very clear-cut idea here about what are the input and what are the output  data types in each function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `input()` its returning an int:

then when you do `list(numbers)` you are trying to make a list from an int thats why you are getting the error

to make a list from the number do

```
number = [number]
```

then number is a list that you can call `len()` on etc

if you are entering the numbers like this for example:

```
1 4 2 5 3 5
```

then just do

```
num_list = numbers.split()
```

and then `num_list` will equal `[1,4,2,5,3,5]`

Comment: well just as i remarked above, input certainly does not return an int--a numerical type--but rather  a text, a string, which is a chain of characters (some of which may or may not be digits)

Comment: use `split()` and then iterate through the list and int each item and if you get an error then delete the item